# How to make a form tag comunicate to another form tag?

Tags: java, forms, jsf, primefaces

I am using JSF 2.2, PrimeFaces and Glassfish and I have this:

```
<h:form id="formularioAltas">
    //more code
    <p:commandButton value="Guardar" action="#{altasBean.agregarRefaccion()}" />
</h:form>

<h:form id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" prependId="false" rendered="#{altasBean.estado}">
    // more code here
</h:form>
```

And I need `formularioAltas` to tell `myForm` that the value of the boolean property `estado` has changed. I uderstand it like doing a simple `update` to `myForm` when the `commandButton` is executed but that cant be cause they are in diferent forms. I needed this way cause I have problems uploading files to the server so I decided to use two different forms. I have working this forms but I want to show only `myForm` when the `commandButton` is executed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<p:commandButton value="Guardar" action="#{altasBean.agregarRefaccion()}" update=":myForm" />
```

`:` because you climb the container hierarchy one step up to the container which contains both forms and `myForm` because that's her name.